# I keep getting this ValueError: operation parameter must be str

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm making an register method to a SQLITE database, but I keep getting this ValueError: `ValueError: operation parameter must be str`

Heres the code:

```
import sys
import os
from os import environ
import utils.messages as m
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('data.db')

cursor = con.cursor()

def login(con):
    print("Welcome to your dashboard.")
    s.sleep(0.5)
    print("Do you want to login [l] or register [r]?")
    log_reg = input("> ")

    if log_reg == "l":
        username = input("Username: ")
        password = input("Password: ")

        cursor.execute(f"SELECT 1 FROM USERDATA WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?", (username, password))
    
        user_exists = cursor.fetchone() is not None

        if not user_exists:
            print("Username/password combination not found!")
            sys.exit(1)
    
        print(f"Hi, {username}!")
        pass

    elif log_reg == "r":
        s.sleep(0.7)
        print("What will your username be?")
        registerUsername = input("> ")
        s.sleep(0.7)
        print("What will your password be?")
        registerPassword = input("> ")

        cursor.execute('''SELECT USERNAME FROM USERDATA WHERE USERNAME = ?''', (registerUsername,))

        user_exists2 = cursor.fetchone() is not None

        if user_exists2:
            s.sleep(0.7)
            print("This username is already in use!")
            exit()
        elif not user_exists2:
            sql = ''' INSERT INTO USERDATA(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
                      VALUES(?,?); ''', (registerUsername, registerPassword)
            cursor.execute(sql)
            con.commit()
            s.sleep(0.7)
            print("Succesfully registered!")
            s.sleep(0.7)
            print("Restart the CLI to log in.")
            cursor.close()
            exit()
```

I keep getting the error on line 52 (`cursor.execute(sql)`). Can anyone help me? Using strings as in `cursor.execute('sql')` doesn't help either. I searched up multiple things on Google but it doesn't have answers for me.

Edit: @Or Y

```
sql = f''' INSERT INTO USERDATA(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
                     VALUES({registerUsername},{registerPassword}); '''
           cursor.execute(sql)
           con.commit()
           s.sleep(0.7)
           print("Succesfully registered!")
           s.sleep(0.7)
           print("Restart the CLI to log in.")
           cursor.close()
           exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
sql = ''' INSERT INTO USERDATA(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
                      VALUES(?,?); ''', (registerUsername, registerPassword)
```

with:

```
sql = f''' INSERT INTO USERDATA(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
                      VALUES({registerUsername},{registerPassword}) '''
```

Comment: I got this error: 
```File "c:/Users/Glibberige Gozer/dash/main.py", line 52, in login
    cursor.execute(sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ";": syntax error```

Comment: @GlibberigeGozer What is your python version?

Comment: I got Python 3.7.4.

Comment: @GlibberigeGozer Is there a change you pasted something wrong? Can you update the code in the original post?

Comment: Sure thing, hold on

Comment: @GlibberigeGozer Try to remove the semicolon `;` inside the string and see if it works, the one in the VALUES line.

Comment: @GlibberigeGozer Yes

Comment: sorry i forgot, i dont have enough rep to chat

Comment: i got this error message:

```File "c:/Users/Glibberige Gozer/dash/main.py", line 52, in login
    cursor.execute(sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: username```

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: @GlibberigeGozer have you created the DB table first? It won't work otherwise

Comment: Yes, I created it like 4 weeks ago

Comment: @GlibberigeGozer Well then it seems like it has been corrupted or invalidly created, as the column for `username` can not be found in it. try to recreate it

Comment: I think the code is wrong you suggested. Because I inserted 'username' as username and 'password' as password. And the column is in capital letters..

Comment: So that means that the code thinks that the input for username and password are columns.

Comment: @GlibberigeGozer Your SQL query attempts to create a new record in a table name USERDATA with fields USERNAME and PASSWORD and setting their values to the one you've passed in your variables. however it cant find the columns

Comment: i'm even more confused now

Comment: Please have a look at this https://imgur.com/8JnREmd

Comment: So it thinks that inserted username and password are columns and not data that should be inserted into the table.